# Can't update libc6: subprocess old post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault

Something failed in an upgrade from Raspbian 7 to Raspbian 8.
I have found threads with similar title to this one, and have tried many things,
but I always get the same error.

Node is at a remote location on a limited bandwidth line, so it is not practical
to do a full rebuild.

The most informative message I get is with "dpkg -C":

```
root@mynode# dpkg -C
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 libc6:armhf          Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries

The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 libc6-dev:armhf      GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
 libc-dev-bin         GNU C Library: Development binaries
 locales              GNU C Library: National Language (locale) data [support]
 libnih1              NIH Utility Library
 libnih-dbus1         NIH D-Bus Bindings Library
```

But when I try to install or reinstall libc6:armhf, this happens:

```
root@mynode# apt-get --reinstall install  libc6:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.19) but 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I try to install or reinstall libc-bin, I get:

```
root@mynode# apt-get --reinstall install  libc-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc6
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 731 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,124 kB of archives.
After this operation, 870 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 82552 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:armhf 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u8 (using .../libc6_2.19-18+deb8u10_armhf.deb) ...
Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
Checking init scripts...
Unpacking replacement libc6:armhf ...
dpkg: warning: subprocess old post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.19-18+deb8u10_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new post-removal script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed pre-installation script was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.19-18+deb8u10_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am stuck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this Debian, or Raspbian?

Comment: Your kernel logs (`dmesg`) should show the process which caused the segfault; could you [edit] your question to indicate what that is?

Comment: My log begins from the last time it booted.  Since the problem is fixed, I no longer that the relevant part of the log.  kern.log is an empty file.  dmesg and journalctl both say the log starts after the last reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - sort of - I found an identical system that was able to do the upgrade with a problem.  I compared the various files in /etc/apt and found numerous differences.

I copied the entire apt directory from the successful system to the broken one and this corrected the problem.

Good luck to anyone trying to figure out what the correct file content is supposed to be.  Googling this returns 1000's of answers, all of them different.  Lucky for me I had a system which had it correct.  So here is a another configuration for you to try.  This one worked for me on five different systems:

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
root@stn4133:/etc/apt# more sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

/apt/etc/sources.list.d/raspi.list:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
```

You may also have errors telling you that you are missing a public key.
This is because trusted.gpg is incomplete.  To fix this, you can follow
the instructions in this article:
https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/

Comment: Why not take the opportunity to help others trying to figure this out? What differences did you see between the systems?

Comment: Apparently it was the content in /etc/apt.  There were problems with both sources.list and trusteed.gpg.  Since I've never modified with of these files (beyond what is necessary for an upgrade), I don't know why they were different.  I will add the configuration that worked to my original post.